# UIComponent replacement in Flex for mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air

I'm currently working on parsing a web project made on Flex 4.6 and the client wanted to see if it could work on iOS. But I have some UIComponents that don't work. As I understand flex for mobile it's not very compatible with the Halo components.
The app it's like a game, made with sprites and animations, but uses some flex components. So I really need something similar as an UIComponent.
So, what can I do with that UIComponent?
Should I use the Canvas instead, or is there a better option?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand flex for mobile it's not very compatible with the Halo
>   components.

If you're using Flash Builder than, by default, the MX.swc is not placed in the library path of your mobile project.  You can add it manually; and that should work.  [See my answer over here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022577/flex-mobile-project-does-not-support-mxcanvas/13022776#13022776).  Once you add it, you'll have to test to determine whether performance is acceptable or not on an actual device.

However, the parent of every Spark Component is the SkinnableComponent and the SkinnableComponents parent is UIComponent.  If you just have generic UIComponent instances or have components that extend UIComponent you should have no problem.

There are also spark equivalents of many of the MX Components that come with mobile optimized skins.  List and buttons should work fine without issues.

The MX Canvas is a container, so there is no real visual piece to it usually.  The Spark parallel would be a Group; or possibly a SkinnableContainer.